# Connect to SqlServer from CodeIgniter

Tags: php, sql-server, codeigniter, doctrine-orm

I integrated CodeIgniter with Doctrine 2 and when I type parameters to connect to MySql database in database.php file it is working ok, but I cant connect to SqlServer. I downloaded SqlServer driver for php 5.5 and added it to extensions, I typed right parameters in databae.php but it still wont work. It looks like it is looking for MySql database by default.
It says "MySql server has gone away".
Anyone knows why it is still trying to connect to MySql althoguh I changed port, driver, username and password in database.php?

Comment: let me see your code in database.php

Comment: try odbc connection with SQLServer i am using odbc connection work like charm

Comment: Here is the update of the problem: Call to undefined function sqlsrv_connect()